# Should I optimize the median or the mean in symmetric game?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

This is an extension of a problem posed previously [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460107/strategy-game-draw-a-random-number-uniformly-between-0-and-1-and-if-you-like-re).

Removing the "game" element from the original post, you want to maximize your number drawn from distribution $X$. You are permitted one redraw, but if you take it, you must keep that number (it is assumed that the draws are iid).

My question is, what strategy should you adopt. On its surface, the question is similar to the linked post. However, it is not clear to me why a person would choose to maximize the mean rather than the median and whether one choice is in fact better than the other.

Generalizing the answer I posted (see the link). Let $s$ be the minimum value we are willing to take. One obtains the distribution $Y$ based on stopping strategy $s$
$$ f_Y(y) = f_X(y) \left( \int_{-\infty}^s f_X(x) \ dx + I_{y \ge s} \right),$$
where $I$ is the indicator function.

As an example, if $X \sim U(0,1)$. The optimal strategy to maximize the mean is  stopping strategy $s = E(X)$. If instead, we want to maximize the median, it can be shown the strategy should be $s = 1/\sqrt 2$.

If player A adopts the first strategy and player B adopts the second strategy, is there a way to generalize which approach is better?

I have simulated this for $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $X \sim \exp(1)$ and have found that the player employed the mean strategy wins slightly more than 50%, but I could not see why, nor whether this should be true in general (provided that $E(X)$ exists).

**EDIT:** It is possible that this question belongs on statistics rather than math. If that's the case, I will move it there if needed.

Comment: It seems to me that if you want to maximize the mean, it's distribution-dependent, but if you want to maximize the median, it's distribution-independent. In the context of the game from the original question, it mostly doesn't affect the strategy what the distribution $X$ is; the only thing that changes is the threshold value.

Comment: I don't see why it would be distribution independent. It can be shown that the $s$ which maximizes the median is given by
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} = \int_{-\infty}^s f_X(x) \ dx, $$
which to me is not distribution independent. My question centers on the observation that both players are maximizing a measure of central tendency and getting different results. This part is not unusual to me. What is unusual is that when they play a game of who wins by choosing different strategies $s$, that one is better than the other.

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too tersely. What I mean is that the game only depends on the order statistics—you don't care how much you beat the other person by, only that you beat them—so that a broadly arbitrary distribution $X$ can be tied back to the uniform distribution in a Radon-Nikodym-ish sort of way. So if the strategy for the uniform distribution was "reroll if the result was less than $1/2$ (the median), else keep", then all you do is find what $1/2$ maps to in the distribution $X$ (its median), and that will be the corresponding strategy for $X$.

Comment: So by "distribution independent" I really just meant that we can solve the problem for the uniform distribution and extend that to other distributions R-N-wise. I did not mean to imply that the precise strategy that maximizes the median value does not depend on the distribution. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: You say *Removing the "game" element from the original post*, but this fundamentally affects the answer.  If Player B is trying to do better than Player A in a single run of the game, then the optimal strategy maximises the probability of Player B beating Player A and this need not involve maximising the mean or median of the distribution of Player B's score.

Comment: But each player makes decisions independently. So I’m wondering what strategy truly maximizes a player’s score.