# Why Is Probabiliy of Winning in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460107/ is as stated?

Tags: probability

I can't comment on questions until I get enough reputation so asking a it as a separate question.

In [Strategy game: draw a random number uniformly between 0 and 1 and if you like redraw. You win if your number is bigger than mine.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460107/) in answer provided by [Henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4465122/1208808)
it is stated that probability of player B winning is
$$
    \int_0^1F_t(x)f_s(x)\mathrm{d}x
$$
Can someone elaborate why?

Thanks!

Comment: $f_s(x)$ is the density for Player B ending up with a score of $x$. $F_t(x)$ is the probability player A ends up with a score of $x$ or less.  The two scores are independent and the probability of a tie is $0$. So the probability of player B winning is the product of these, integrated over $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes sense now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will summarize what was said in the thread first: the only valid strategy for a player is to pick a cutoff $t$, wherein if your first number is less than $t$, reroll. Henry then defines the cdf of the result, where
$$F_t(x) = \mathbb{P}(\text{with cutoff $t$, the chance of the player getting less than x)},$$
and the pdf of the result, $f_s(x)$, the probability density function derived from the cutoff $s$.

Let the first player use a cutoff of $t$, and the second player use a cutoff of $s$.

In this sense, $F_t(x)$ basically tells us: if the second player rolls $x$ (this is $f_s(x)$, what is the chance the first player loses? So, the probability of the first player losing is calculated by first figuring out what the second player rolled (this is $x$,) multiplying by the probability that the first player loses in that situation (this is $F_t(x)$,) and then averaging this over the possible rolls the second player gets;
$$\int_0^1 f_s(x)\cdot F_t(x)dx.$$
If it helps, you can also think of this as a joint distribution: let $f(x,y) = f_t(x)f_s(y)$ be the joint pdf of the results of player 1 and player 2.
The region in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ that corresponds to player 2 winning is when $y > x$, so we get that the probability of player 2 winning is
$$\int \int_{y > x} f(x,y)dx\;dy = \int_0^1 \int_0^y f_t(x) dx \cdot f_s(y)dy := \int_0^1 F_t(y)f_s(y)dy.$$